# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, findbugs

i got this Error i didn't know how i would to solve it any solution Please.

when i initialise firebase im main function it show me this white screnn and flutter icon:

[image]

[image]

but when i delete this initliation this firebase app run successfully as it is:

[image]

and show me those errors

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 9):

I just forget to add Google services plugin in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: D'Oh! Smacking my head!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have firebase_core in your pubspec.yaml
Then, just use the following in your main:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

run

> flutter clean

and

> flutter pub get

in your terminal.

If it still fails, please go step by step following the firebase documentation. It should work. https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android

Comment: i just followed this link that you've sent to me and I've got the answer.thank's for help.

Answer (score 2):

For my problem, I solved it by changing firebase initialization in `main.dart` as followed.

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(options:DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
```

Answer (score 1):

Above solution didn't work for me.

The problem is that flutter cannot connect to firebase. It can be due to incorrect `google-services.json` generating or pasting on wrong location.

Firebase has flutter tool to automatically inject the required configs, which actually worked for me.

- https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/ this worked well.
- This tool automatically takes the config and upload them to firebase.

Prerequisite

- Install firebase CLI. curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash